# How do I run Register-ScheduledJob from a script running as SYSTEM?

Tags: windows, permissions, powershell, scheduled-task

I'm trying to run `Register-ScheduledJob` from a script executing as SYSTEM (from an external deployment tool), but I get an error. This must be initially invoked as SYSTEM due to the way the deployment tool works.

---

To reproduce this problem (requires powershell.exe running as SYSTEM), I created *another* scheduled job as follows:

- Run as user account: `SYSTEM`
- Action:

  - Run: `powershell.exe`
  - Arguments: `Register-ScheduledJob -name testjob -filepath c:\target.ps1 > C:\testjob.txt 2>&1`

> Note: if you want to reproduce this yourself, you'll also have to create `c:\target.ps1` as an empty file.

This job can then be executed from Task Scheduler UI, and you can see the output in `c:\testjob.txt`.

---

When the script runs `Register-ScheduledJob`, it shows the following error:

```
Register-ScheduledJob : An error occurred while registering scheduled job 
definition testjob to the Windows Task Scheduler.  The Task Scheduler error is: 
(32,4):UserId:.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledJob -name testjob -filepath c:\target.ps1 > C:\testjob.txt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...edJobDefini 
   tion:ScheduledJobDefinition) [Register-ScheduledJob], ScheduledJobExceptio  
  n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantRegisterScheduledJobDefinition,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.ScheduledJob.RegisterScheduledJobCommand
```

As far as I can tell this has *something* to do with not being able to create a job as the SYSTEM user. I'm not really concerned with what `target.ps1` actually runs as (eg it doesn't have to be SYSTEM), so long as it's an account that I don't have to manage a password for.

My script has to be initially invoked as SYSTEM (from a service which is running as SYSTEM), so how can I use it to create a scheduled job?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that `Register-ScheduledJob -Credential` can't eat build-in accounts and people just couldn't register PS-jobs. But [this was hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846688/powershell-run-job-at-startup-with-admin-rights-using-scheduledjob/60552857#60552857).

Now, I see that you can't use `Register-ScheduledJob` as you run it under the SYSTEM account. Ooh, pretty fair trouble.

**Can you try the following?**

As we know...

> -Credential
>   Specifies a user account that has permission to run the scheduled job. **The default is the current user.**

OK, then let's provide something to the `Register-ScheduledJob -Credential` instead of the default SYSTEM.

- Register some credentials-in-text in your build tool.
- Create a PSCredential object by using [PowerShell RunAs Confirm-Free Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password/56771810#56771810).
- Provide the credential object to `Register-ScheduledJob -Credential $someCred`
- The switch your job to be [run under the SYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846688/powershell-run-job-at-startup-with-admin-rights-using-scheduledjob/60552857#60552857).

This is quite complicated,
**so consider the following thoughts.**

I use **Register-ScheduledJob** when I want to schedule a PowerShell script block. It is just convenient. But if you want to schedule a *ps1 script file* then you can use **Register-ScheduledTask**. Why not? There are examples over there.

There are ways to run deployment tool projects/jobs under another account.

Many build tools have password masking as a protection against password logging.
Register a non-admin account by adding text credentials to your build tool.
Create a PSCredential object by using [PowerShell RunAs Confirm-Free Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password/56771810#56771810).
Run you logic as a script block by using
`Invoke-Command -Credential $someCreds -ScriptBlock { ... }`

Yeah, I made it easier and I just switched my build-machines to a "flesh" account. )
This also can be a solution. And this is a good practice, too.

Time is gone, I believe you've found something else. )